# Correct term to describe data that has had values removed/trimmed?

Tags: dataset, terminology, outliers

What terms can I use to describe data that does not include +- 3 z-values? 
More importantly which are flat out wrong to use?

> a) sample 
> b) sample group 
> c) dataset 
> d) population 
> e) other

Comment: My choice is other. Note, the term Winsorization, refers to a data set, where outliers are replaced with the nearest “good” data, as opposed to truncating them completely.

Comment: Winsorization, is very interesting, thank you for the reference. However, if I'm not replacing the values, then would I describe the data as a trimmed dataset, and any descriptive stats trimmed stats, example: trimmed mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment:  Illustration of trimmed mean, truncation, and Winsorization:

Finding a 'trimming mean' involves temporarily ignoring the highest and lowest t% of a sample. For example a 5% trimmed mean takes the mean of values between quantiles 0.05 and 0.95. [In R.]

5% [Trimmed mean in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.37/topics/Trim) is computed without changing the dataset.

```
set.seed(801)
x = rexp(100); mean(x)
[1] 1.090642
mean(x, trim=.05)
[1] 0.9858567
summary(x); sd(x);  length(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01174 0.22450 0.83253 1.09064 1.57869 5.18616 
[1] 1.07786  # SD
[1] 100      # n
q = quantile(x,c(.05,.95))
```

[Truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_(statistics)#:%7E:text=Truncation%20is%20similar%20to%20but,of%20those%20omitted%20being%20kept.) reduces the size of the dataset.

```
x.trunk = x[x>=q[1] & x<=q[2]]
mean(x.trunk)
[1] 0.9858567   # same as trimmed mean, from reduced dataset
summary(x.trunk);  sd(x.trunk);  length(x.trunk)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.05542 0.24847 0.83253 0.98586 1.50557 3.26938 
[1] 0.840819  # SD
[1] 90        # n
```

[90% Winsorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing) changes the values of smallest and largest values in a dataset,
but maintains sample size.

```
x.win = x
x.win[x < q[1]] = q[1]
x.win[x > q[2]] = q[2]
head(sort(x.win))
[1] 0.05537047 0.05537047 0.05537047 0.05537047 0.05537047 0.05541696
tail(sort(x.win))
[1] 3.269378 3.272387 3.272387 3.272387 3.272387 3.272387
summary(x.win);  sd(x.win);  length(x.win)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.05537 0.22450 0.83253 1.05366 1.57869 3.27239 
[1] 0.9688655  # SD
[1] 100        # n
```

Comment: Thank you @BruceET from this I gather that I would describe the data shown as a "truncated dataset of values within +- 3 standard deviations" or something along those lines?

Comment: Maybe say 'truncated at $\pm 3$ standard deviations from the mean'. But in discussion of _terminology_ for altering data in this way, we have not discussed whether this sort of truncation is a good idea. Sometime OK, often not.